# rspec build many tests at once with each, problem with memoized variables

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

I need to build some quite repetitive rspec tests, and would like to DRY it up a bit.

```
describe 'filter' do
  let!(:filter_1) { create :filterable, value: 1 }
  let!(:filter_2) { create :filterable, value: 2 }
  let!(:filter_3) { create :filterable, value: 3 }
  let!(:filter_4) { create :filterable, value: 4 }

  expected = { 
              a: filter_1,
              b: filter_2,
              c: filter_3,
              d: filter_4
            }
  expected.each do |filter, expected| 
    describe "by #{filter}" do
      let(:expected) { [ expected ] }
      it "shows only #{filter}" do
        get :index, filter: filter
        expect(assigns[:filters]).to match_array expected
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm basically defining a hash with my filters and expected results, and build a test for each one.

the problem is how to specify the expected result in the hash.

this example raises an error:

````
rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:667:in `method_missing': `filter_1` 
is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). 
It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) 
or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). 
(RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)```

I think the memoized variables are only available within an `it` block. 

how could I solve this? 

thanks,
````

Comment: You should try a solution using a method or a `Proc` I'll post an example using a `Proc`. I suggest to use  `Let` and `Let!` only when you really need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
describe 'filter' do
  expected_filters = -> () do
    filter_1 =  '1'
    filter_2 = '2'
    { a: filter_1, b: filter_2 }
  end
  
  

  expected_filters.().each do |filter, expected| 
    describe "by #{filter}" do
      it "shows only #{filter}" do
        expect(filter).to be_instance_of(Symbol)
        expect(expected).to be_instance_of(String)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But if  you need the code in `Let!` to be run for any example try to find a solution with a method definition but you have to change something in the test code as actually is.